# Why ansible template file looped

Tags: ansible

Defined two variables:

```
vars:
  var1: a
  var2: b
```

Use these two variables in a template file:

```
{{ var1 }} string
{{ var2 }} string
```

Set template file to servers(two servers):

```
- name: Update file
  template:
    src: file.j2
    dest: /etc/somefile
```

Then check the `/etc/somefile` on the servers, got this content:

```
$ cat /etc/somefile
b string
b string
```

But not:

```
$ cat /etc/somefile
a string
b string
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step by step you'll have to find out where do the values of the variables come from. Start with the debug task

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ var1 }} {{ var2 }}"

- name: Update file
  template:
    src: file.j2
    dest: /etc/somefile
```

See [Variable precedence: Where should I put a variable?](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable). The playbook vars precedence is 12. and can be overridden by 13-22.